# fs.appendFileSync returning "undefinied"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to make the bot save the message content from a user into a `txt` file. It is returning as "undefined".
I would appreciate any help.

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dG11.png

Comment: You need to provide more context, what is returning `undefined`?

Comment: Please, provide your code as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

## Welcome to Stack Overflow

#### In the future **please** supply your code as text pasted in the question.

So what you're doing there is saving the OUTCOME of the function to `addcontent1`
You are running `fs.appendFileSync(addpath1,<value2>)` And then saving whatever that function returns.

I also want you to note that you didn't supply `<value2>` which means it defaults to `undefined`. Thats why it's saving/returning it as `undefined`

I better solution would be:

```
   addcontent1 = function(passIn,callback){
       fs.appendFileSync(addpath1,passIn,'utf-8', callback);
   }
   // ...
   addcontent1(message.content,function(err){
       if(err) throw err;
   });
```